# Cookies in a mobile app

Tags: angularjs, cookies, storage

I am creating an Hybrid mobile app with Ionic Framework.

I need to persist some data in the DOM, it is only Username and Email in one single view so I don't need too much storage. I am using **cookies-ngCookies** with Angular trough a service named `$cookieStore`, anyways, this service is attached to the regular cookies. So far, I know that the cookies is a storage that browser provides, but what about when the app is downloaded from AppStore or Google Play?

1-) if cookies is something that the browser provides, what would happen with the cookies in this case that I will not be opening the app from a browser ?

2-) Are cookies still supported when you download the app from a Store, or cookies are only supported by the browsers?

**UPDATE**

what do you use when you create an app and you want to persist data in the DOM ? like user info: profile picture, name, email ?

My problem is that when I wasn't using cookies: the user was logged in, and he was able to see his info in the DOM, but once he refreshes the app, he was still logged in, but all the info was lost.

Comment: Cookies and local storage have different uses. Local storage is for local client-side persistence of data. Cookies is for data stored on the client that is sent to the server on every request. Which one do you need?

Comment: I need Cookies I guess. I need it because: an user enters to the app, then he logs in with username and password, and I have a view where that info will be displayed(email and username), if the user refreshes the page, that info should persist there in the DOM. So, there I am sending the user info to the server, am I right ? @NewDev

Comment: It sounds that you don't need either. It's not a good idea to persist a password in cleartext either in cookies or in local storage. And typically, a cookie is used as an authentication token (given as a replacement of sending username/password on every request).

Comment: @NewDev I am using Firebase so I am sending a token.

Comment: Ok.. so, then why do you think you need a cookie?

Comment: @NewDev I don't know exactly, what do I need in this case ? Right now I have ngCookies and it is doing what I want.

Comment: Ah, I misread - I thought you wanted to save username/password - not username/email. In any case, I told you what the difference is between a cookie and local storage. Figure out which one suits you (because, frankly I don't understand your use case) and use that one. And I don't understand the question itself. What "is still supported"? What does it mean "what would happen with cookies"? Try to reformulate the question (by editing - not in comments) to explain precisely what you have and want to achieve

Comment: @NewDev ok, see the question now.

Comment: You have 2 different and unrelated questions here (that should have been 3 different SO questions). 1) Can I use `ngCookies` when the app runs in some app environment; 2) How to persist client-side user data between sessions/refreshes? #1 is answered below (I believe correctly, but I don't know for sure). And #2 - both local storage and cookies persist between refreshes. In fact persisting "in the DOM" (I assume you mean by using `element.data()`) would not persist across sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use cordova/phonegap?
They provide a sandbox supporting your Cookies, Localstorage, ..

If you work with a lot of data you might consider local database like pouchdb.

Comment: Ok, but then: should I remove ngCookies and work only with LocalStorage? sorry but I did not get you.